# How to change translator for validator messages in Zend framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I try to set the default translator by using PhpArray in resources/languages/fr/Zend_validate :

```
$translator = new Translator();
        $translator->addTranslationFile(
                'phpArray',
                'resources/languages/fr/Zend_Validate.php',
                'default',
                'fr_FR'
        );
        AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator($translator);
```

But it doesn't work ! 
I have this error : 
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Model\AbstractValidator' not found in...

Otherwise I take care of import this class : 
use Zend\Validator;

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing a `use` statement?

```
use Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator;
```

or try:

`\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator` instead of `AbstractValidator`;

Edit: I noticed you mentioned the `use Zend\Validator;` you should then be able to use `Validator\AbstractValidator`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

\Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator::setDefaultTranslator(new \Zend\Mvc\I18n\Translator($translator));